# Collect calls and save them to csv

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible if I have a list of url parse them in `python` and take this server calls key/values without need to open any browser manually and save them to a local file?

The only library I found for csv is `pandas` but anything for the first part. Any example will be perfect for me.

Comment: You can use the inbuilt `csv` package to read data from a csv. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html or https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html depending on your Python version.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the use of one of the built in or available libraries that let python actually perform the browser like operations and record the results, filter them and then use the built in csv library to output the results.

You will probably need one of the lower level libraries:

- urllib/urllib2/urllib3

And you may need to override, one or more, of the methods to record the transaction data that you are looking for.